Why does Swift FileManager.default.urls(...) return a different result than ObjC implementation (iOS simulator)?
React Native Async Storage calls the following method to find an appropriate directory in the Simulator's file system:
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) .firstObject
By opening Finder, it can be observed this evaluates on my machine to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6A36BEDF-71DA-4A9B-9CDD-EBC6BCE11BC0/data/Containers/Data/Application/D258BA62-85FF-4288-95BF-D1318C63B947/Library/Application Support/
I now hope, in my SwiftUI extension widget for the same React Native iOS app, to access this folder. But when I call FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first, this evaluates to /Users/brandon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6A36BEDF-71DA-4A9B-9CDD-EBC6BCE11BC0/data/Library/Application Support/
As you can see, the results for these are quite different. Why does the Swift method appear to find a different folder and how I can I alter it to access the one the ObjC method finds?
I'm expecting the Swift code to evaluate to the same as that generated by React Native Async Storage in ObjC

I think the difference lies in the different executable types - one being an application, the other being an extension (which often operate via app groups)

Always use FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) don't hard code urls

The problem is not Swift vs Objective-C. Try the two from within a same app and you will receive the folder.
The problem is app vs widget, each of which has a unique, separate sandbox. You can use an “app group” if you want the app and widget access a shared container.

See Configuring App Groups for information about adding the app group capability in Xcode.

You access this container with containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: from Objective-C:
NSURL *baseUrl = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.domain.foo"];


And from Swift, use containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:):
guard let baseUrl = FileManager.default
    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.domain.foo")
else {
    fatalError("app group container not found")
}




It sounds like you're saying there is no way for my widget to know the file path to the directory created by my app, when the app calls the ObjC method mentioned in my OP, and that the solution is to either patch React Native Async Storage to write the file to a shared container or create a native module to accomplish the same. Is that right?

I’m not a React Native Async Storage user, so I’m not sure I can advise you on this. FWIW, issue #126 seems to (a) have raised the question; and (b) has been marked as “complete”. So maybe there are some breadcrumbs you can follow from there to find the solution for your issue.
